# jquery mobile data-role='list-divider'?

Tags: jquery, list, mobile

Is there an easy way to find out if a particular divider list item (li) has child items or not? The trick here is that the divider and the child items are actually at the same level in jquery mobile.

```
<ul>
        <li id='i0' data-role="list-divider">Has Items<li/>
        <li>Candidate Item 1</li>
        <li id='i1' data-role="list-divider">Has no Items<li/>
        <li id='i2' data-role="list-divider">Has no Items<li/>
        <li id='i3' data-role="list-divider">Has Items<li/>
        <li>Candidate Item 2</li>
</ul>
```

I need a jquery expression that will tell me if a particular li has child items (based on the divider role) or not?

```
HasChildren($("#i0"))
```

I have tried, but cannot find a solution without writing a lot of iterative code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a function to do that:

```
function hasChildren ($li) {
  if ($li.next().is('[data-role="list-divider"]'))
    return false
  return true
}
```

Hope this helps. By the way, all the closing tags for the `list-divider` `<li>`s are incorrect. They should be `</li>`, not `<li/>`. Hope this helps!